# visualizing orientation (zenith and azimuth) data (e.g. with a circular or spherical histogram)?

Tags: data-visualization, multivariate-analysis, circular-statistics

I want to understand the distribution of orientation angles in a 3D image (represented as a triangular mesh).

For each triangle in the image I have zenith ($\Theta$) and azimuth ($\phi$)

[image]

And I can compute histograms for each:

[image]

Is there a way that I can combine the information contained in these images into a single histogram representing the joint distribution of these variables?

Comment: Can you give more details on the actual problem? What prevents you from doing the same you did in 1D also in 2D?

Comment: I'd like to wrap these circular distributions, e.g. so that the values of $\phi$ meet at $\pm \pi$

Comment: the actual problem is related to 3D realizations of a plant canopy, as described in [Song et al 2013](http://www.publish.csiro.au/?act=view_file&file_id=FP12056.pdf) to summarize the distribution of  leaf elements in a plant canopy.

Comment: It seems no real problem if this wrapping is your only point. Just choose an histogram-grid $z_j$ such that the boundaries are either connected (e.g. regions $[-1,-0.9], ... , [0.9,1]$) or wrap into the other end (e.g. $ [-0.95,-0.85] ... , [0.95,-0.95]$).

Answer (score 1):

The way to determine a two-dimensional histogram is very similar to the one-dimensional case.

Basically in 1D, you sum up all knots within a certain interval or bin. That is for $\varphi$, you count all points in the "beam" $\varphi \in [\varphi_i-\Delta \varphi_i, \varphi + \Delta \varphi]$, $\theta \in [-1,1]$, and divide by the total number of points. This procedure can be seen to give a Monte-Carlo estimate of the integral

$$P_i =\int_{\varphi_i-\Delta \varphi}^{\varphi_i-\Delta \varphi} d\varphi \int_{0}^\pi  d\theta \, \sin(\theta) \ p(r,\varphi, \theta)\\
=\int_{\varphi_i-\Delta \varphi}^{\varphi_i-\Delta \varphi} d\varphi \int_{-1}^1  dz \ \tilde p(r,\varphi, z)=\frac{N_i}{N} $$

where $p(r,\varphi, \theta)$ is the density which generates the points (which admittedly will hardly become continuous for your picture), and $\tilde p(r,\varphi, z)$ is the transformed density for $z=\cos \theta$.

In result, you get for each azimuthal grid point $\varphi_i$ a real number $P_i$ (alternatively, you can also plot unnormalized values $N_i$). The same goes for $z_j$ (caution: due to the volume element of the sphere, if you look for equally space bins, you have to work in the transformed coordinate $z$, otherwise you won't get consistent bin-volumes).

Similarly, in the two-dimensional case, you span a two-dimensional grid of regions  $\varphi \in [\varphi_i-\Delta \varphi_i, \varphi + \Delta \varphi]$, $z \in [z_j - \Delta z,z_j + \Delta z]$, count the number of knots and obtain the coresponding approximate probabilities $P_{ij}$. Finally, you simply plot the data in a 3D picture with the data given in the form

$$\varphi_i, \ z_j, \ P_{ij}$$

Such three-dimensional plots are supported by almost any plot program.

Comment: Despite the unfortunate wording at the end, this question makes it clear that the data consist of $(\theta,\phi)$ pairs describing points on a *sphere.* The approaches you suggest will not work correctly because they are designed for Euclidean density estimates. Moreover, the area elements in your integrals, $d\phi d\theta$, are not the correct ones for the sphere.

Comment: Thanks for your point, I made a rough correction. I'll further ask the OP for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you're ignoring `r` for each triangle, your coordinates describe points on a sphere and your problem corresponds to visualization of data across longitude/latitude values. The good news is that that's a well-studied problem with lots of tools available. The bad news is no really good solutions have been found for representing a globe in 2D. Nonetheless, it's such a common problem that we've come to accept the limitations of a few common [projections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_map_projections). A 2D heatmap with a map projection may be useful.

Comment: you can take a look of the software visumap that enables you to embed high dimensional data into 2d or 3d manifolds (like sphere, projective plane, S3, etc.) and provides interface for interactive exploration.